# Run pyright in single file mode and some questions

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp, pyright

I have pyright set up as an lsp in neovim and my configuration is like this:

```lua
lspconfig.pyright.setup({
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  root_dir = function(fname)
    local root_files = {
      "pyproject.toml",
      "setup.py",
      "setup.cfg",
      "requirements.txt",
      "Pipfile",
      "pyrightconfig.json",
    }
    return util.root_pattern(table.unpack(root_files))(fname)
        or util.find_git_ancestor(fname)
        or util.path.dirname(fname)
  end,
  flags = { debounce_text_changes = 300 },
  settings = {
    python = {
      analysis = {
        autoSearchPaths = true,
        diagnosticMode = "openFilesOnly",
        useLibraryCodeForTypes = true,
        typeCheckingMode = "basic",
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I have some questions regarding the configuration above:

1- When I set `root_dir = util.root_pattern(vim.loop.cwd())` the `root_dir` in LspInfo is always set as `/` even if my current working directory is somewhere else. Why does that happen?

2- What's the function of `debounce_text_changes = 300` flag?

3- In this configuration, it sets the `root_dir` current working directory if there's no project file found. However I want it to run in `single file mode` when there are no project files/folders (eg .git/setup.py) exist. How do I accomplish that?

4- What does `autoSearchPaths = true` do?

5- What does using `LibraryCode` for `Types` mean? What is `LibraryCode` and what are `Types`?

Thank you in advance!
All the best

Comment: Never ever paste any code/configuration/anything you don't understand into your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
root_dir = vim.loop.cwd()
```

The `debounce_text_changes` parameter control how often the server is query (if set to 300 the LSP server will be query maximum every 300 ms even if you type three character in that interval)

The `autoSearchPath` is an option that make the LSP server looking for some additional locations to resolve import (it seems that currently it is only the `src` subfolder see [code](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/295db6af56c36cb11b41f35d2032050a7e85fcf2/packages/pyright-internal/src/common/configOptions.ts#L1457))

The LSP server needs to deduce the signature of the library function you ate using in your code (e.g. to deduce/check the type compatibility) it can deduce it from stub if any or from an analysis of the library code.

Answer (score 0):

The workspaces mechanism is one of the worst mechanisms in neovim.
You don't want it to be the root folder.
I used to add a folder to workspaces folders, but then it came back to me whenever I switched project.

How I solved it?

```
function _G.set_workspace_dir(dir)
    vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder(dir)
    local folders = vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()
    for i = 1, #folders do
        if dir ~= folders[i] then
            vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder(folders[i])
        end
    end
end

require("workspaces").setup({
path = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/workspaces",
 hooks = {
        open =  function()
 set_workspace_dir(require'workspaces'.path())
 print("workspace dir is " .. require'workspaces'.path())
end,
}})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '_ws', function() 
        _G.set_workspace_dir(vim.fn.input('Directory: ',vim.fn.getcwd())) 
    end 
        )
```

Uses `natecraddock/workspaces.nvim` to provide a single folder path to each project (called workspace). So when I open the workspace ,it sets the right path.  And I use this function to set manually the workspace dir if needed.

Regarding 3, you can remove all folders from workspaces list(accessible by `vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()`) , using a code similar to the defined function.